# Toolbar title issue

Tags: android, android-toolbar

It's very easy to set Title to the toolbar and so I am setting a title to the toolbar based on my need like Messages, Documents, etc.

So the issue is when I set the title like for example "Odometer" it shows it with the dot at the end. After that when I open the keyboard the word "Odometer" shown fully.

Toolbar showing title with 3 dots, Following is a screenshot for same.

**Question** : What I need to do? To display full title without having 3 dots???

[image]

Any Help will be Appreciated.

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: need more data.Can you post an image with documents written with dot and provide some codes too

Comment: Hey, I have update the Question can you please look?

Comment: put the xml code for the toolbar

Comment: Added xml code. Kindly have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using appcompat v7 : `23.1.1` with no problem.
Here is my toolbar xml. try it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/tb"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry! We have coded the same with appcompat v7 : 28.0.0 but not working.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

      <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:title="@string/menuLabel1a"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_normal"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
                android:maxLines="1" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

now set the text to `TextView` it should work

Comment: That i know but i don't won't to add textview. I'm having the toolbar alredy why should i use TextView for just setting the title.